# Fetching transaction in several iterations

Tags: yodlee

I need to fetch transactions of our users accounts (investment accounts, if it matters).

Now, my favorite method is "Approach 2", as mentioned in [this official guide](https://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions), as it requires using only one API method and generally, seems simpler to implement. But, I have a few questions on this approach:

1. Can I use this approach? I'm asking since the [API method page](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) doesn't remind it but rather mentions only 'approach 1'.
2. The numbering of transactions - when I request transactions shall I start from transaction number 0 or 1 ? The couple of pages linked above each uses different version :-)
3. Lastly - the page that details the approaches talks about **setFirstCall** parameter, yet the method API page doesn't mention it. I just wanted to verify that I need not care of this parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: no one to reply?... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)  Can I use this approach? I'm asking since the API method page
>   doesn't remind it but rather mentions only 'approach 1'.

Yes you can use approach 2 from this [guide](https://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions#How_far_back_does_the_transaction_search_on_the_consumers%27_transaction_history_go.3F_Is_there_a_limit.3F)

> 2) The numbering of transactions - when I request transactions shall I
>   start from transaction number 0 or 1 ? The couple of pages linked
>   above each uses different version :-)

Please start from 1. We have updated the guide accordingly.

> 3) Lastly - the page that details the approaches talks about
>   setFirstCall parameter, yet the method API page doesn't mention it. I
>   just wanted to verify that I need not care of this parameter.

This parameter has to be passed to use approach 2.

it should be passed as  `transactionSearchRequest.firstCall = false`